# Proof of the evaluation of a trigonometric sum.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

How to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin{kx} = \frac{\cos{\frac{x}{2} - \cos{(n+\frac{1}{2})x}}}{2\sin{\frac{x}{2}}}$ for every positive integer $n$ where $x$ is a real number such that $\sin{\frac{x}{2}}\neq 0$?

**My idea**
I am thinking of considering the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2\sin{kx} \sin{\frac{x}{2}}$ as an approach to this proof, but I am not sure how to proceed. Is my approach correct? Any tips or hints given? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know about complex numbers and Euler's formula $e^{ikx}=\cos(kx)+i\sin(kx)$? This really is the most efficient way I think to approach the question (because for integer $k$, we have $e^{ikx}=(e^{ix})^k$, so summing it up is easy using the formula for a geometric sum). Alternatively, you can try induction and the various addition formulae.

Comment: btw the benefit of using the complex approach is that you can easily obtain the related identity $\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(kx)=\frac{\sin\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)x-\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}$.

Comment: @metamorphy great reference thank you! I need a bit more time to digest all its contents haha

Comment: @peek-a-boo thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: @metamorphy Finally, I have proved it successfully. Thanks for sharing this link!